# CSS Issue - Big white space on the right side

Tags: css, width, padding

I created a WordPresss theme on my blog - http://misstravelgirl.com/

The issue is that when you shrink the browser to about 1060 pixels width or less, you see a big white space on the right side next to the brown box. I am aware that it's the padding in the #palette div that is causing it because when I set the padding to 0, it fixes the problem. However, I still want the padding for the text. So, how can I fix the problem by removing the white space without adjusting the padding?

Answer (score 1):

Without any code examples, my help is limited. However, I'd suggest setting the width of the problem `div` to 100% so that no matter the size of the browser window, it will always fill it. I try to do most of my widths and heights in percentages for this exact reason.
You could also try something like `overflow-x: hidden;`

It would be better if you could post the code you think is the issue.

Comment: Here is my css stylesheet - http://misstravelgirl.com/wp-content/themes/Blog%202/style.css

As you can see in the stylesheet, I do have the percent set, but the padding still somehow interferes the setup.

Comment: you have this:

`html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: #ff;
}`

try adding `height: 100%; width: 100%;` to this as well.

Then, for the div you said you were having problems with (`#palette`, correct?) your width is only set to `1000px`. Try setting this width to `100%` too.

Also, I'm not sure what you're using your `#wrapper` div for, but if it is a wrapper for the whole page then that too needs to be changed to `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try adding padding to your #content div instead of your #palette div and use a media query? 
`@media only screen and (max-width : 1060px) {
      #content {
          padding: 20px;
      }
}`